# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sockjs-node/info'

Tags: angular, angular-universal, sockjs

I am getting this error when running angular universal on my local machine with `npm run dev:ssr`.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. 
URL Segment: 'sockjs-node/info'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sockjs-node/info'
```

I am not sure if it is a **local** error or what.

Thanks,
J

Comment: You should not call websockets when the app is running server side

Comment: Obviously, but it gets called anyway somehow internally.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and realised it must be the Angular analytics getting sent. Switching analytics off using the command:

```
ng analytics off
```

solved it for me.